# How to avoid data clashing with Other User details in jsp web application?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am developing one web application in JSP/Servlets and hosted my application in tomcat server my problem is, when users hit same button in same page, but difference pc, the data will be clashing. which is 2-3 users will get others user data displaying on screen. this makes missunderstanding towards my users. i have used many way to solve this problems. but the result is still the same.. can all of u help me. thanks.

Comment: Include your code for access to the data that is leaking

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the users authenticating?  If so (And most likely even if not) each user should have a session and you should be able to save the data in that session using HttpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object).

If users are not authenticating you may have to do something to start sessions propagating between requests.

Storing data as fields in the servlet will result in the data being shared between all uses of the system.

Comment: i am using session also, the problem may occuer when user access the application in a same time.